# httpClient.PostAsync - Windows store application - mvc webapi

Tags: .net, windows, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-runtime

it's my first question on this page.
I have application in mvc webapi and Windows Store application and I want to request my object with W8 app to web api:

my object:

```
 var objobj = new ObjectCompleteAdd()
            {
                NameObject = "Name",
                DescriptionObject = "Description",
                isActveObject = true,
                ContractStartObject = DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01"),
                CityAdress = " CityAdress",
                PostCodeAdress = "PostCode",
}
```

class in BLL:

```
 public class ObjectCompleteAdd
    {  
        public string NameObject { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionObject { get; set; }
        public bool? isActveObject { get; set; }
        public DateTime ContractStartObject { get; set; }
        public string CityAdress { get; set; }
        public string PostCodeAdress { get; set; }
}
```

and my function:

```
  var dataContractSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObjectCompleteAdd));
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, objobj);
            HttpContent content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);  

            await client.PostAsync("api/ObjectISApi",content);
```

in webapi I have post:

```
  // POST api/ObjectISApi    
        public HttpResponseMessage PostObjectIS(ObjectCompleteAdd obj)
        {     
            ObjectIS.AddNewObject(obj);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        }
```

it's doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

After serializing your object, rewind the stream, set the position to zero:

```
var dataContractSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObjectCompleteAdd));
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, objobj);

// Rewind stream.
memoryStream.Position = 0;

HttpContent content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
```

**UPDATE:** Well, I think you need to also modify your server code, to properly deserialize the JSON object you are sending. ASP.NET does not deserialize JSON automatically.

```
public ActionResult PostObjectIS()
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
    string contentString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var oca = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<ObjectCompleteAdd>(contentString);
    Debug.WriteLine(oca.NameObject);

    return View();
}
```